# Puzzle of atrm vs at -d

Tags: linux, at

I've found some puzzle with `atrm` command I can't understand. The man page for `at` says that `atrm` is an alias for `at -d`. The `file /usr/bin/atrm` command says that it is a symbolic link to `at`.

Now if `atrm` is a link to `at` then my understanding is that `atrm <jobid>` and `at <jobid>` commands should be equivalent, but they aren't (`atrm <jobid>` and `at -d <jobid>` are), `at <jobid>` command just shows "Garbled time" error.

How is that? I mean how being a symbolic link to `at`, `atrm` can call `at` with a `-d` option? What do I miss?

P.S. Linux distro in question is Debian 7.3

Thank you

Comment: Another example of the pattern described above is `/bin/rbash` symbolic link which will start `bash` with `-r` flag (restricted mode)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Program code can know what the name of the executable was that launched it. It's possible that the `at` program does something like this:

```
if (my name is 'atrm') then
   add '-d' parmeter
end
do stuff like regular 'at' program.
```